# Read in data and set it to the index of a DataFrame with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to iterate through the rows of a DataFrame and assign values to a new DataFrame. I've accomplished that task indirectly like this:

```
#first I read the data from df1 and assign it to df2 if something happens
counter = 0                         #line1
for index,row in df1.iterrows():    #line2
    value = row['df1_col']          #line3
    value2 = row['df1_col2']          #line4
    #try unzipping a file (pseudo code)                  
        df2.loc[counter,'df2_col'] = value  #line5
        counter += 1                        #line6
    #except
        print("Error, could not unzip {}")  #line7

#then I set the desired index for df2
df2 = df2.set_index(['df2_col'])  #line7
```

Is there a way to assign the values to the index of df2 directly in line5? Sorry my original question was unclear. I'm creating an index based on the something happening.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of ways to do this.  According to your code, all you've done is created an empty `df2` dataframe with an index of values from `df1.df1_col`.  You could do this directly like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([], df1.df1_col)
#                   ^     ^
#                   |     |
# specifies no data, yet  |
#                        defines the index
```

If you are concerned about having to filter `df1` then you can do:

```
# cond is some boolean mask representing a condition to filter on.
# I'll make one up for you.
cond = df1.df1_col > 10
df2 = pd.DataFrame([], df1.loc[cond, 'df1_col'])
```

Comment: I edited my code to be more clear. I need to assign the value based on a condition.

Comment: @sparrow I edited my condition to account for your edit.

Comment: Sorry, was a bit unclear again so edited again. It's actually in response to an event (unzipping a file).

Answer (score 0):

No need to iterate, you can do:

```
df2.index = df1['df1_col']
```

If you really want to iterate, save it to a list and set the index.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Javier. In my case the problem is that I only want to copy to df2 if certain conditions are met in df1 so I can't clone the index.